# How to use SIM908-C BY UNV shield

Tags: c++, gps

I have a shield with a SIM for `GSM/GPRS` communications and `GPS module`.
As visible in top-left corner its name is "SIM908-C EVB v1.0 designed by UNV".

[image]

I found some basic information on Arduino forum but they are discordant about baud rate so I tried different configuration: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=302982.0

I tried to use several libraries (such as `sim900` or `tinyGPS`) for GPRS communication or simply for getting GPS position, but without results. Shield not respond to serial commands at any baud rate.

Connections that I used:

```
shield <--> aruino mega
GPRS TXD <--> D2
GPRS RXD <--> D3
GPS TXD <--> D4
GPS RXD <--> D5
GND <--> GND
5V <--> VCC_MCU
```

Obviously I set D2..D5 in library according to TX/RX pins on shield.

I also tried with a simply code to send AT commands and... no results again.
Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2,3);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Begin");
    mySerial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
    if (mySerial.available())
        Serial.write(mySerial.read());
    if (Serial.available())
       mySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

Shield seems to be well powered and connected to SGM net. Infact:

- power led: is on
- ring led: is on
- net status: blinks one time in three seconds

Has someone used this shield? What is a good library to use?
Every help is very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried other baud rates with this sketch? 9600, 19200, 57600, etc? Is your serial monitor set to "Both NL & CR" at the bottom? Explain the connections between the Arduino and the module.

Comment: Thank you for interest.
Shield not respond to serial commands at any baud rate.
Serial monitor is set to "Both NL & CR".

Comment: Dont connect the GPS pins for now. Try using the other hardware serial ports of the Mega like Serial1 instead of SoftwareSerial. You say the module is powered well. How exactly are you powering the module? Try using 4V/2A supply. Also connect the VccMcu pin to the same 4V source and level-shift TX signals from the Arduino to 4V.

Comment: OK, I'll try connecting TX1 <-> GPRS_RXD and RX1 <-> GPRS_TXD.
I'm using a 12V/1.5A power supply connected to the shield. Arduino Mega is connected via USB to computer.
I'm not sure what do you mean with "level-shift TX signals from the Arduino to 4V"

Comment: Surely you arent connecting the 12V supply directly to the shield? There must be some regulator in the middle? By level-shift, I mean using a simple voltage divider to reduce 5V signals from the Arduino TX line to 4V that can be used by the module. Does the module have any sort of datasheet about the voltages it supports?

Comment: From datasheet I find that power supply can be 5-18V and Vcc_mcu must be connect to level of serial port: I think that is correct to connect to 5V of Arduino.
I'm trying now (baud rate 9600) and with AT command I receive a response made by ten bytes:
65 (A)
84 (T)
13 (CR)
10 (LF)
13 (CR)
10 (LF)
79 (O)
75 (K)
13 (CR)
10 (LF)
It seems to work.

How to use GPS, now?

Comment: What did you change that made it work now? I havent used GPS with these modules before but I imagine another serial port is all you need. Download the sim908 AT command set.

Comment: I tried a lot of configurations: I don't know exactly what is different now.
I think that the main difference is the use of TX/RX native serial ports of Arduino Mega.

Comment: I thought as much. I had the same problem with a similar module and a Mega. Didnt work till I used Serial3.